# Fetch latest checked in information using TfvcHttpClient Class

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to fetch latest checked in information using `TfvcHttpClient` class from a specific folder in Team Foundation Server using its client API from a console application.

Please help how can I achieve it? I have personal access token and below mentioned is able to connect by using it:

Code:

```
string uri = _uri;

string personalAccessToken = _personalAccessToken;

string project = _project;

string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalAccessToken)));


//create wiql object
var wiql = new
{
    query = "Select [State], [Title] " +
            "From WorkItems " +
            "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' " +
            "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
            "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
            "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
};

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

    //serialize the wiql object into a json string   
    var postValue = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wiql), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); //mediaType needs to be application/json for a post call

    //send query to REST endpoint to return list of id's from query
    var method = new HttpMethod("POST");
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri + "/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.2") { Content = postValue };
    var httpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
}
```

I have tried below mentioned code for achieving:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, new 
VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, _personalAccessToken));

var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>(); // connect to the build server subpart
var sourceControlServer = connection.GetClient<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.TfvcHttpClient>(); // connect to the TFS source control subpart

var changesets = buildServer.GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync("client-rsa", 1, 5).Result;
foreach (var changeset in changesets)
{
    var csDetail = sourceControlServer.GetChangesetAsync("client-rsa", Convert.ToInt32(changeset.Id.Replace("C", string.Empty).Trim()), includeDetails: true).Result;
    var checkinNote = csDetail.CheckinNotes?.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name == "My check-in note");
    if (checkinNote != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", changeset.Id, changeset.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Check-in note: {0}", checkinNote.Value);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Warning: {0} has no check-in note", changeset.Id);
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having? The code sample you provided doesn't interact with version control in any way. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Daniel the code which i posted i am using it for getting workitem information and i want help to fetch latest checked in information using TfvcHttpClient Class from a specific folder in TeamFoundationServer using its client HTTP API

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried, and what isn't working with the code you wrote?

Comment: VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, _personalAccessToken));

                var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>(); // connect to the build server subpart
                var sourceControlServer = connection.GetClient<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.TfvcHttpClient>(); // connect to the TFS source control subpart
 var changesets = buildServer.GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync("client-rsa", 1, 5).Result;

Comment: foreach (var changeset in changesets)
                {
var csDetail = sourceControlServer.GetChangesetAsync("client-rsa", Convert.ToInt32(changeset.Id.Replace("C", string.Empty).Trim()), includeDetails: true).Result;
 var checkinNote = csDetail.CheckinNotes?.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name == "My check-in note");
                    if (checkinNote != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", changeset.Id, changeset.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Check-in note: {0}", checkinNote.Value);           }else}

Comment: What about your code is not working? What results does it give? What results are you expecting it to give? What steps have you taken to correct the issue? People can't help you unless you provide a clear problem statement.

Comment: Hi @Veejay, what's the detail of "checked in information" would you like to get, did you mean you want to get changeset detail info  like using `tf changeset xxx /noprompt` command?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple sample code which use `TfvcHttpClient` to get the latest changeset information:

```
    string purl = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com";
    string projectname = "projectname";

    VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
    creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
    VssConnection vc = new VssConnection(new Uri(purl),creds);

    TfvcHttpClient thc = vc.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();

    TfvcChangesetSearchCriteria tcsc = new TfvcChangesetSearchCriteria();

    //Specify the server path of the folder
    tcsc.ItemPath = "$/XXXX/XXXX";
    //Get the entire history of the specified path
    List<TfvcChangesetRef> changerefs = thc.GetChangesetsAsync(projectname,null,null,null,null,tcsc).Result;
    //Get the latest changeset ref
    TfvcChangesetRef changeref = changerefs.First();

    //Get the changeset
    TfvcChangeset changeset = thc.GetChangesetAsync(projectname,changeref.ChangesetId).Result;

    //Get the detailed changes
    List<TfvcChange> changes = thc.GetChangesetChangesAsync(changeref.ChangesetId).Result;
    foreach (TfvcChange cg in changes)
    {
        //Code to read detail information
    }
```